# How can I get the array in chrome's bookmark API?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

if I write:

```
var source = new Array();
function doSomething(a){
   chrome.bookmarks.search(a,function(items){
      for(var i = 0;i<items.length;i++)
      {
          source[i] = items[i];

      }

   });
   console.log(source[0].title);
   alert(source[0].title);

}
```

in the console I can see the values,but what alerted is "undefined".

can someone tell me why and how to write to get the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are executing `alert` in the wrong scope - you should do this in the callback function. Try this:

```
function doSomething(a){
   chrome.bookmarks.search(a,function(items){
      var source = [];
      for(var i = 0;i<items.length;i++)
      {
          source[i] = items[i];

      }
      console.log(source[0].title);
      alert(source[0].title);   
      doSomethingWithResult(source); 
   });      

}
```

You have seen the right value in the console because it shows reference to the value which have been already filled in this moment (in the callback function).

Comment: Yes,you are right.But if I want to return source[0].title,it returns undefined again.How can I return the values?

Comment: That's the way how callback function works ;) Instead - you should put `executeFunctionWithResult(source[0])` in the place of `alert(source[0].title)`

Comment: I want source[] to be sended to contentscript by message passing.Is it difficult?

Comment: Great - so please mark my answer as a correct for future readers